# How to set a Single key Mnemonic in button in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, key-bindings

I am working on a project and I want to set Mnemonic on buttons. But the problem is Mnemonic works on pairing key example (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) etc. But I want it to be on single key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- have look at KeyBindings,
- then you can to attach any Key to the JButton

Here is one example code for your help, just Press <kbd>C</kbd> on the Keyboard :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Action;

public class ButtonExample
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Button Mnemonic Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();      
        Action buttonAction = new ButtonAction("CLICK ME"
                                , "This is a Click Me JButton");
        button = new JButton(buttonAction);                                             
        button.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('c'), "Click Me Button");
        button.getActionMap().put("Click Me Button", buttonAction);

        contentPane.add(button);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public ButtonAction(String text, String desc)
        {
            super(text);
            putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "BINGO, you SAW me.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new ButtonExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Again Pardon me for the edit, couldn't stop myself, since I can not answer now, the same thing as said by you. So added one example code. Please do have a look, if it's good enough for the guidance, else remove it, feel free as always :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw glitch is that the key does something else then clicking the button, that's most probably not intended. Instead, use an Action to configure the button and re-use that same instance in the ActionMap

Comment: @kleopatra are you meaning to use JButton.doClick()

Comment: I'm aware that it's a bit unfair you getting the downvote for @nIcEcOw 's code - want to give any of you an incentive correct it :-) BTW, doClick in the action _is_ an option, just not optimal, IMO, mainly because you should _always_ favour Actions over ActionListener+properties to configure a button

Comment: @kleopatra : I just realized, that's what I thought I missed, as once told by trash god too about using Action :-), but since now I am away from my computer on my iPad, I need some time to edit the code again. I be obliged if you do this much needed favour :-)

Comment: @kleopatra : If I go through the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), I see they had explained in the same way, as I had done. I guess I am missing something as always, that you won't reveal soon as always :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw I don't see any relation of that tutorial link to your code - where in the ActionDemo do they use an ActionMap? ahh .. you did it, perfect!

Comment: @kleopatra : If I go by the way they said, in that then the OP's problem will persist, in the sense I have to again press `ALT + C` I guess, so I used KeyBinding as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: @nIcEcOw never critisized the ActionMap usage, that was perfect right from the start :-) But the Action stored there _must_ do the _exact same_ thingy as clicking or pressing space or whatever user gesture is available to trigger the button

Comment: @kleopatra : Ahha, I just realized, that's the problem I am facing in my present Project. Shall I ask a new question regarding - If I assign a Key to say a `JTextField` like Press N, then this thingy must show my Account Name in that field, then I cann't press N, inside this `JTextField`, even if I wanted to provide a name that has N in it, since it always shows me, the UserName at the press of N key. How to go about this thingy ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw don't assign a single key that corresponds to a typeable char :-)